# Angular 2 NgModel doesn't work

Tags: typescript, browserify, angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm starting my transition from Angular 1 to Angular 2. I tried to do simple things first so I wrote a component:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgModel} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div>
    <div>Value is {{ value }}</div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" />
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [NgModel]
})
export class App {
  value: string;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app></app>

    <script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(bundle.js do only the bootstrapping of `app` component)

I expect after I type something into the textbox, I should get the same text in the `div`. But it doesn't happen.

Why doesn't my code work?

Regards,
Sarun

**UPDATE** I assume I may configure my build system incorrectly, so I include my `gulpfile.js`, `package.json` and `boot.ts`.

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var tsify = require('tsify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('ts', function() {
  browserify({
    debug: true
  })
  .add('source/ts/boot.ts')
  .plugin(tsify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
    loadMaps: true
  }))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('source/ts/**/*.ts', ['ts']);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-angular2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.34.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-exec": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-live-server": "0.0.29",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.2",
    "tsify": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

boot.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from './app';

bootstrap(App);
```

Comment: I've tried this code (Typescript), and it works fine. The only issue I see here is that its missing a lot of angular scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long dig in to the docs and a long googling, I finally found the answer.

(This answer may change in the future, refer to Angular Documentation)

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/bundles/overview.md

As @pixelbits mentioned, I missed a couple of dependencies `rxjs` and `angular2-polyfills`, the latter is a polyfill for two other dependencies `zone.js` and `reflect-metadata` and this must be included in a `<script>` tag only.

Things I need to do is:

1. Remove `reflect-metadata` import from `boot.ts` and add `rxjs` import to it.
2. Add a `<script>` tag for `angular2-polyfills.js` to `index.html`

And voila! It works as expected.

Thanks to @pixelbits, @Zyzle and @Günter Zöchbauer for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your import of `ngModel` isn't valid (or needed) take it out and it should run fine see here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/tGqtYOXpPp0qdDpUNrtZ?p=preview

Comment: I've included my gulpfile and boot.ts in the post. Could you check if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not a browserify user myself but as @pixelbits pointed out it doesn't actually look like your bundling angular itself or including the `angular-polyfills.js` in your index file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `FORM_DIRECTIVES`, `NgModel` is not enough.
I get the error `No value accessor for '' in [AST]` when I only add `NgModel` (in Dart).
The [example in the code documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9e44dd85ada181b11be869841da2c157b095ee07/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_model.ts#L42) also uses `FORM_DIRECTIVES`

Comment: `FORM_DIRECTIVES` is actually no longer required as an import since a few alphas back, same goes for `CORE_DIRECTIVES` and I think a few others

Comment: I saw that mentioned a few times, but it doesn't work without `FORM_DIRECTIVES`. Maybe that's just in Dart.

Comment: Hmmn, could be. Works fine in TypeScript though.

Comment: Still doesn't work, moreover, strange thing happend. If I set a value to `value` in the component's constructor, I got that value shown in both the textbox and the `div`. But if I change the value in the textbox, the value in the `div` doesn't change. Wierd.

Comment: Or maybe I missed some dependency in my build system? I use `gulp`, `browserify` and `tsify` for my build.