# bind to ngModel but got "undefined" ( Angular 8)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

I have bound a property to `ngModel` , but it always gave me **undefined**

```html
  <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="input-alumni"
              id="input-alumni-2"
              value="true"
              [(ngModel)]="isAlumni"
              (change)="handleAlumiSelect($event)"
              required
            />
            <label for="input-alumni-2">&nbsp;Yes</label>
          </div>
<div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="input-alumni"
              id="input-alumni-1"
              value="false"
              [(ngModel)]="isAlumni"
              (change)="handleAlumiSelect($event)"
            />
            <label for="input-alumni-1">&nbsp;No</label>
          </div>
```

I print it in  handleAlumiSelect:

```
public isAlumni: any;
  handleAlumiSelect(e: any) {
    console.log('handleAlumiSelect');
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(this.isAlumni);
  }
```

e.target.value shows me the right anwser, but this.isAlumni is always ("undefined").

can any one tell me why?

Comment: Not sure why but I can see the values correctly using your code. stackblitz here - https://angular-jeksse.stackblitz.io

Comment: Do you assign the value of ``e.target.value`` to var ``isAlumni`` ?

Comment: @Abdulrahman shouldn't have to, `ngModel` should be doing it

Comment: Why `(change)` over `(ngModelChange)`?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the code

Comment: can we use `(change)="handleAlumiSelect(isAlumni)"`

Comment: Try following this link , It might help 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578381/angular-2-ngmodel-doesnt-work

Comment: Iam getting values correctly even with your code.. @Shinji035

Comment: yes guys , these code works well if I put them in a individual demo, but it just didn't  work in my project...

Answer (score 0):

Do not use value with ngModel, remove it first.

```
 <input type="radio" name="input-alumni" id="input-alumni-1" [(ngModel)]="isAlumni" (change)="handleAlumiSelect($event)"/>
```

Comment: sorry , it is not work, otherwise I need the value to determine something .I know it is strange because totally same code works well in the demo . but not works in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it's nothing wrong about my code. there are some other errors in my html file , because I'm updating the project form an AngularJS project. those errors maybe affected the binding. So I just remove all codes that lead to errors. and the ngmodel works.